# How to combine 2 sql statements

Tags: sql

I am trying to retrieve data for a client from an old database that they have. The data I need is a mix of these 2 sql statements. How would I combine them to get all the data from the enrol_stud table and Stud_Haddress table in the second statement.

Statement 1 - I want all the data from Enrol_Stud and Stud_Haddress included in statement 2

```
select enrol_stud.*, stud_haddress.*
from enrol_stud_forms 
inner join enrol_stud on enrol_stud_forms.student_id = enrol_stud.student_id
```

Statement 2 I want the data from the 2 tables above included in the statement below.

```
SELECT contact.*, vsmc.*, concarer1.*, salcarer2.*,  contact.firstname ||' 
'||contact.surname as STUDENT, salcarer1.salutation as CARER1_TITLE, concarer1.firstname as CARER1_FIRSTNAME, concarer1.surname  as CARER1_SURNAME, concarer1.email_address as CARER1_EMAIL, salcarer2.salutation as CARER2_TITLE, concarer2.firstname as CARER2_FIRSTNAME, concarer2.surname as CARER2_SURNAME, concarer2.email_address as CARER2_EMAIL

FROM get_currently_enroled_students ('now') gces
INNER JOIN student on gces.student_id = student.student_id
INNER JOIN contact on student.contact_id=contact.contact_id
INNER JOIN view_Student_mail_carers vsmc on student.student_id=vsmc.student_id
INNER JOIN contact concarer1 on vsmc.carer1_contact_id=concarer1.contact_id
INNER JOIN contact concarer2 on vsmc.carer2_contact_id=concarer2.contact_id
INNER JOIN salutation salcarer1 on concarer1.salutation_id=salcarer1.salutation_id
INNER JOIN salutation salcarer2 on concarer2.salutation_id=salcarer2.salutation_id
ORDER BY contact.surname, contact.firstname
```

I know it is in the joins, I just can't work out how to include them.

Comment: Statement 1 should have these lines at the end of it.  inner join ridbc_stud_haddress on ridbc_enrol_stud.student_id = ridbc_stud_haddress.student_id

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below, include the columns from first statement per post as well include the joins as pointed below

```
SELECT contact.*, 
vsmc.*, 
enrol_stud.*, <- here
stud_haddress.*, <-here
concarer1.*, 
salcarer2.*,  
contact.firstname ||' '||contact.surname as STUDENT, 
salcarer1.salutation as CARER1_TITLE, 
concarer1.firstname as CARER1_FIRSTNAME, 
concarer1.surname  as CARER1_SURNAME, 
concarer1.email_address as CARER1_EMAIL, 
salcarer2.salutation as CARER2_TITLE, 
concarer2.firstname as CARER2_FIRSTNAME, 
concarer2.surname as CARER2_SURNAME, 
concarer2.email_address as CARER2_EMAIL

FROM get_currently_enroled_students ('now') gces
INNER JOIN enrol_stud_forms on gces.student_id = enrol_stud_forms.student_id <- here
INNER JOIN enrol_stud on enrol_stud.student_id = gces.student_id <- here
INNER JOIN student on gces.student_id = student.student_id
INNER JOIN contact on student.contact_id=contact.contact_id
INNER JOIN view_Student_mail_carers vsmc on student.student_id=vsmc.student_id
INNER JOIN contact concarer1 on vsmc.carer1_contact_id=concarer1.contact_id
INNER JOIN contact concarer2 on vsmc.carer2_contact_id=concarer2.contact_id
INNER JOIN salutation salcarer1 
on concarer1.salutation_id=salcarer1.salutation_id
INNER JOIN salutation salcarer2 
on concarer2.salutation_id=salcarer2.salutation_id
ORDER BY contact.surname, contact.firstname
```

Comment: Thanks. That has been a huge help.

Comment: @user3847672, then it's time to accept the answer by clicking the check button under voting up/down button.